# How to make a loop in a javascript function using EJS

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

I've written this script. It works fine, but when I'm adding the loop it doesn't work. Is there a mistake in the structure of the loop or another thing?

```
<p id="f"></p>
<script>
    var resultat = '{ "name":"multiplication matricielle", "age":30, "city":"New York"}'
    var obj = JSON.parse(resultat);
    document.getElementById("id1").value = obj.name;
    document.getElementById("id2").value = obj.age;
    document.getElementById("id3").value = obj.city;
</script>


<script>
    function compare() {
        a = "yes";
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < '<%=inf.length%>'; i++) {

            if ('<%=inf[i].nom%>' == obj.name && '<%=inf[i].sortie%>' == obj.city) {
                return a;
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('f').innerHTML = compare();
</script>
```

Comment: remove "<%=***%> and try inside script tag it not required

Comment: please share console log error

Comment: i < '<%=inf.length%>' will not work i < inf.length will work based on length of inf

Comment: @VinodLouis `inf` still won't be defined though.

Comment: @Kev yes I also saw its undefined so wrote based on the value of inf

Comment: The question is, why would you use a script tag and `innerHTML` and not just output the result directly inside the element with EJS ?

Comment: inf is defined in the server

Comment: Have you passed `inf` to the template

Comment: i've even tested this function and it works fine
function compare(){
     a="yes";
     var i;
 
if ('<%=inf[1].nom%>'==obj.name && '<%=inf[1].sortie%>'== obj.city){
   return a; }
}

Answer (score 0):

You have to return outside of your loop and you can change a little:

```js
function compare() {
  var a = "No"; // <---initialize with default value
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < parseInt('<%=inf.length%>', 10); i++) { // parse as number
    if ('<%=inf[i].nom%>' == obj.name && '<%=inf[i].sortie%>' == obj.city) {
      a = "Yes"; // if check is true change the value
    }
  }
  return a; // <--- now return it here
}
```

---

For your comment:
You need to parse a string number to a valid number

```
parseInt('<%=inf.length%>', 10); // You have to parse it as number.
```

Comment: the function works without the loop so the problem is somewhere in the loop structure

Comment: @Maki you have to parse the string as a number for loop.

Comment: Or you could do `<%- inf.length %>`